# how to connect with non secure websocket on https?

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, websocket

I am using a websocket to get market data it was working fine but when i install SSL on my dedicated server my websockets stopped working i found that i am calling a non secure websocket on secure place means i was trying to connect with websocket using WS after that i tried to connect with server using WSS but its giving error that connection refused. is there any way to call non secure websocket on https something like in iframe or please tell me the reason why its refusing WSS connection??

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Please post your code... and, you could setup your web socket to be on HTTPS too

Comment: Terminate each sentence with a dot (`.`). Omission of dots makes your question difficult to read, so most people leave your question without reading it to the end. Also, capitalize 'i' and the first letter of each sentence, if you want people to read your question.